# netbeans Rent-a-Flat sample Application_Model_PropertyMapper not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans

i'm testing netbeans IDE 7.1 zend framework sample Rent-a-Flat.

main page seems ok. already set up virtualhosts and it displays welcome page. when i clicked on **Add New Offer** links it shows an error:

```
Warning: include(Application\Form\PropertyForm.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Loader.php on line 83

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Application\Form\PropertyForm.php' for inclusion (include_path='T:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RentAFlat-Zend\application/../library;;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Loader.php on line 83

Fatal error: Class 'Application_Form_PropertyForm' not found in T:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RentAFlat-Zend\application\controllers\PropertyController.php on line 82
```

since this is my first try on zend framework and netbeans IDE, I have no idea what is going wrong.

i'm using Windows Vista, Apache and PHP5.2 on XAMPP. maybe i'm missing some steps. the instruction only shows how to setup virtualhosts.

**update1:** this is example `application.ini` maybe something wrong with path:

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Rent-A-Flat software/demo but normally your forms would go in `Application\forms\` rather than `Application\Form\` but maybe they set up the autoloader to work like that.  Is there a directory in Application called Form with `PropertyForm.php` in it?

Comment: i have no idea. using default values and source code on zend-framework is likely same. see updates on my question.

Comment: are you a netbeans user and new to ZF or are you also new to netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the project in My Netbeans and I got it to work. 
Things to check.

1. Make sure Zend Framework is in your PHP `include_path` or in the `/library` of your project. if in the library put the `ZendFramework/library/Zend/` in the `/application/library` so it looks like `/application/library/Zend/`
2. Make sure you set up the application in netbeans properly... make sure the sources are accessible to your server (permissions), make sure the run configuration is correct (with ZF it's not needed to specify an Index file)

this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application_Form_PropertyForm' not found in T:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RentAFlat-Zend\application\controllers\PropertyController.php on line 82
```

suggests that you need to copy sources to your web root directory

the Vhost that netbeans specifies is little lean try something similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\www\RentAFlat\public"
    ServerName RentAFlat.local
    ErrorLog "C:\Zend\ZendServer\logs\RentAFlat.local.log"
    <directory "C:\www\RentAFlat">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

make sure the DocRoot points to the `/application/public` folder

it's also very helpful to put the path to the ZF /bin directory in your windows PATH so that you can use the command line interface that ZF has (there is an interface for the cli in netbeans)

comment if you need more clarification

also ZF has a pretty good quickstart use this [link](https://sites.google.com/a/jschoenwolf.com/www/home/create-your-project) to see a detailed setup tutorial based on ZF quickstart